# How to prove: if X is non-empty, then (A × X) ⊆ (B × X) implies A ⊆ B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If X is non-empty, then (A × X) ⊆ (B × X) implies A ⊆ B. how to prove this theorem?

I cannot go forward after a certain point since I cant remove $x \in X$ from both sides of the implication. Please help.

Comment: Start with $z \in A$ whatever; $X$ not empty means that $x \in X$ for some $x$. Thus $(z,x) \in (A \times X) \subseteq (B \times X)$ and thus  $(z,x) \in (B \times X)$. This means that $z \in B$ and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in A$; since $X$ is non-empty, there exists $x\in X$.

Then form the pair $(a,x)$ and see what set it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

$(a,x)\in (A\times X) \subseteq (B\times X) \implies (a,x)\in (B\times X)\implies a\in A \land a\in B\implies A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A\times X\subseteq B\times X$. If we expand things out a bit, we get
$$\{(a,x)\mid a\in A\land x\in X\} \subseteq \{(b,x)\mid b\in B\land x\in X\},$$
namely 
$$a\in A\land x\in X \implies b\in B\land x\in X.$$
Now, I suppose your problem from here is the “$x\in X$” on either side. Just note that this implication is equivalent to 
$$a\in A\implies  b\in B \quad \land \quad x\in X\implies x\in X,$$
since you’ve already hypothesized that $x\in X$ and it is redundant to be stated twice. Thus, $A\subseteq B$.